# What would this distribution be?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

If I flip a coin $n$ times, count the heads, put an $x$ over the number of heads, then I repeat this with $n-1$ heads, and repeat what function would these $x$'s aproximate, I think it might be $f(x)=x^{-1}$ but I'm not sure, could someone please provide the function, and the proof of why it will fit this curve.

EDIT: the $x$'s would be like

x  . . . . .
x x . . x.

1 2 3 4 5

if for the total I got 2 cases with one x, a single case for both 2 and 4 heads, and no cases with 3 or 4 heads

Comment: What do you mean, "put an $x$ over the number of heads"?

Comment: @6005 oh yes I did! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: No, I'm asking what *you* mean. I can't make any sense of that statement.

Comment: that makes no sense. Please state exactly what procedure you are applying. First list out the coin tosses? List out the numbers from $1$ to $n$? Then put $x$s somewhere? You need to explain yourself.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now.